# How to use dotnet format to format the whole project inside a subfolder?

Tags: c#, .net, husky, lint-staged, dotnet-format

I have a .Net 5 app and want to use dotnet format. First I added [commitlint, husky](https://commitlint.js.org/#/guides-local-setup) and [lint-staged](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged) to the repository. The folder structure looks like

```
.
├── package.json
└── MyCsharpProject
    ├── MyCsharpProject.sln
    └── Assembly1
```

The configured package.json file looks like

```
{
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.cs": "dotnet format --include"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^12.1.1",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^12.1.1",
    "husky": "^6.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "husky install"
  }
}
```

The hook fails with this output

```
> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
[STARTED] Preparing...
[SUCCESS] Preparing...
[STARTED] Running tasks...
[STARTED] Running tasks for *.cs
[STARTED] dotnet format --include
[FAILED] dotnet format --include [FAILED]
[FAILED] dotnet format --include [FAILED]
[SUCCESS] Running tasks...
[STARTED] Applying modifications...
[SKIPPED] Skipped because of errors from tasks.
[STARTED] Reverting to original state because of errors...
[SUCCESS] Reverting to original state because of errors...
[STARTED] Cleaning up...
[SUCCESS] Cleaning up...

✖ dotnet format --include:
  Could not find a MSBuild project file or solution file in '/home/.../my-repository'. Specify which to use with the <workspace> argument.
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

I tried to modify the dotnet command in the package.json file to

> dotnet format ./MyCsharpProject/MyCsharpProject.sln

but unfortunately I get multiple errors

```
> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
[STARTED] Preparing...
[SUCCESS] Preparing...
[STARTED] Running tasks...
[STARTED] Running tasks for *.cs
[STARTED] dotnet format ./MyCsharpProject/MyCsharpProject.sln
[FAILED] dotnet format ./MyCsharpProject/MyCsharpProject.sln [FAILED]
[FAILED] dotnet format ./MyCsharpProject/MyCsharpProject.sln [FAILED]
[SUCCESS] Running tasks...
[STARTED] Applying modifications...
[SKIPPED] Skipped because of errors from tasks.
[STARTED] Reverting to original state because of errors...
[SUCCESS] Reverting to original state because of errors...
[STARTED] Cleaning up...
[SUCCESS] Cleaning up...

✖ dotnet format ./MyCsharpProject/MyCsharpProject.sln:
Unrecognized command or argument '/home/.../my-repository/MyCsharpProject/Assembly1/SubFolder/AFile.cs'
Unrecognized command or argument '/home/.../my-repository/MyCsharpProject/Assembly1/SubFolder/BFile.cs'
Unrecognized command or argument '/home/.../my-repository/MyCsharpProject/Assembly2/AFile.cs'
```

What is the correct command to simply lint the whole C# project?

---

**Update**

I tried to change this line in the package.json from

`"*.cs": "dotnet format --include"`

to

`"*.cs": "dotnet format ./MyCsharpProject/MyCsharpProject.sln"`

Now the pre-commit checks work fine. The only thing I'm thinking about is  that when I modify a .cs file and add multiple empty lines with some tabs I get this output

```
> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
[STARTED] Preparing...
[SUCCESS] Preparing...
[STARTED] Running tasks...
[STARTED] Running tasks for *.cs
[STARTED] dotnet format ./MyCsharpProject/MyCsharpProject.sln
[FAILED] dotnet format ./MyCsharpProject/MyCsharpProject.sln [FAILED]
[FAILED] dotnet format ./MyCsharpProject/MyCsharpProject.sln [FAILED]
[SUCCESS] Running tasks...
[STARTED] Applying modifications...
[SKIPPED] Skipped because of errors from tasks.
[STARTED] Reverting to original state because of errors...
[SUCCESS] Reverting to original state because of errors...
[STARTED] Cleaning up...
[SUCCESS] Cleaning up...

✖ dotnet format ./MyCsharpProject/MyCsharpProject.sln:
Unrecognized command or argument '/home/.../my-repository/MyCsharpProject/Assembly1/MyFile.cs'

dotnet-format
  dotnet-format

Usage:
  dotnet-format [options] [<workspace>]

Arguments:
  <workspace>  A path to a solution file, a project file, or a folder containing a solution or project file. If a path is not specified then the current directory is used. [default: ]

Options:
  --no-restore                                                             Doesn't execute an implicit restore before formatting.
  -f, --folder                                                             Whether to treat the `<workspace>` argument as a simple folder of files.
  -w, --fix-whitespace                                                     Run whitespace formatting. Run by default when not applying fixes.
  -s, --fix-style <error|info|warn>                                        Run code style analyzers and apply fixes.
  -a, --fix-analyzers <error|info|warn>                                    Run 3rd party analyzers and apply fixes.
  --diagnostics <diagnostics>                                              A space separated list of diagnostic ids to use as a filter when fixing code style or 3rd party issues. [default: ]
  --include <include>                                                      A list of relative file or folder paths to include in formatting. All files are formatted if empty. [default: ]
  --exclude <exclude>                                                      A list of relative file or folder paths to exclude from formatting. [default: ]
  --check                                                                  Formats files without saving changes to disk. Terminates with a non-zero exit code if any files were formatted.
  --report <report-path>                                                   Accepts a file path, which if provided, will produce a json report in the given directory.
  -v, --verbosity <d|detailed|diag|diagnostic|m|minimal|n|normal|q|quiet>  Set the verbosity level. Allowed values are q[uiet], m[inimal], n[ormal], d[etailed], and diag[nostic]
  --binarylog <binary-log-path>                                            Log all project or solution load information to a binary log file.
  --version                                                                Show version information
  -?, -h, --help                                                           Show help and usage information

husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

- Why does it say "Unrecognized command or argument" to empty lines with multiple tabs?
- Why is the help section showing up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check your version of dotnet format.
I the new version - v5.1.22507 the feature of format run on solution filter using - `dotnet format solution.slnf`.

This will not work prior to the above version.

please refer the [github](https://github.com/dotnet/format) page.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Please have a look at my "Update" section, I tried to test your suggestion

Comment: Refer to this thread, blank lines are not allowed since november 30: https://github.com/dotnet/format/issues/67

Comment: Yes, this is fine. I'm just wondering about this confusing error message and why the help section is showing up

Comment: I thinks the moment the format encounters error, it is throwing unrecognized command or argument. then prompts the help section for the user to decide how to act. A poor choice of dealing with exception if you ask me.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/format/issues/1156#issuecomment-848023819 :)